# what does the dash `-` before `bash` on 'command not found' errors mean?

Tags: bash

When you enter an invalid command at a bash prompt you get the message

```
-bash: {command}: command not found
```

What does the `-` at the very beginning signify?

Comment: How exactly are you running the command?  I tried to replicate, but I'm not getting the same results - e.g.> `jhgjbjbkjln: command not found` - no `-bash: ` in there.  Are you using `bash` in Unix, Linux, OSX, ...?  I ask because maybe this is something a specific implementation put before the error message by default, and it doesn't mean anything... maybe.

Comment: @jim Try `ssh computername` and your not count command to replicate .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It means that it is a login shell.

From `man bash`:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
>   one
>          started with the --login option.

(In `bash` terminology, the "zeroth" argument is the command name which, in your case, was `bash`.)  `bash` uses this as a signal to do login activities such as executing `.bash_profile`, etc.

One way that the dash may be added automatically is if the shell is started with `exec`.  From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec):

> ```
> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> ```
>
> [...] If the `-l` option is supplied, the  shell places a dash at
>   the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to *command*.

#### Example

Compare these two attempts to run the command `nonexistent`.  First without `-l`:

```
$ exec bash
$ nonexistent
bash: nonexistent: command not found
```

And, second, with:

```
$ exec -l bash
$ nonexistent
-bash: nonexistent: command not found
```

Comment: I think the part of the documentation you're quoting doesn't match up with your explanation. The fact that `exec -l` prepends a dash is a possible way that may cause bash to be run as `-bash`, but that by itself doesn't say that it is a login shell, and there is a very good chance that the OP hasn't used `exec -l` at all. The part of the documentation that says `-bash` makes it a login shell is "INVOCATION A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option."

Comment: @hvd, agreed. Though correct, this answer misses the point.

Comment: "The zeroth argument" is not `bash` terminology, but Unix convention + C indexing: Each program gets passed a parameter list, whose initial entry is the program name, followed by the arguments. Since C arrays are indexed starting with zero, argument zero (that is, the zeroth argument) is the program name, and the actual arguments start with index 1.

Answer (score 15):

The other answer is fine as far as it goes, but it's worth mentioning that the feature is more general than bash.

Since ancient times, the `login` program has prepended a dash to `argv[0]` when it executes the user's shell, and the shell has recognized this as a sign that it should behave as a "login shell". It is documented in the V7 man pages here: [login(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition), [sh(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition).

All programs that provide a login-like service (authenticate a user and run a shell) should follow the "prepend dash" rule. For example, sshd does as you can see in [ssh/session.c](http://openbsd.cs.toronto.edu/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/usr.bin/ssh/session.c?rev=1.274) under this comment:

```
/*
 * If we have no command, execute the shell.  In this case, the shell
 * name to be passed in argv[0] is preceded by '-' to indicate that
 * this is a login shell.
 */
```

All shells recognize the leading dash. The equivalent `-l` option doesn't exist in the classic Bourne shell or original csh, but most newer shells (bash, dash, ksh, yash, tcsh, zsh, rc, es, fish and any semi-recent version of csh) have it.

Comment: Even though most shells now have the `-l` option, `login` still doesn't use it. All shells are expected to recognize the prefix on `argv[0]` as the "official" mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of the function `main` is manually set by the parent process rather than preset by kernel. The parent process can set any value as the child's `argv[0]`. See [`man 3 exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

e.g. The parent can do

```c
execlp("bash", "-bash");
```